# How to check if elements of tuple A are in another tuple B and the elements are in the same sequence in the start of tuple_B?

Tags: python

```
tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)
tuple_B = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

this case will be true as tuple_A elements are in tuple_B and in the same order

```
tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)
tuple_B = (1,3,5,4,2,6)
```

but this case should be false as though tuple_A is a subset of tuple_B but tuple_A elements are not in the same order in start of sequence of tuple_B so this is wrong

my code is:

```
if set(tuple_A).issubset(tuple_B):
   return True
else:
   return False
```

Please suggest a short solution!

Comment: Should `1,2,3` be considered a subset of `1,5,2,6,3,7`?

Comment: What you want is a subsequence not a subset.

Comment: But sub-sequece can also happen in any order. tuple_A(1,2,3) should be at the same index in tuple_B at index: [0,1,2].

Comment: if `tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)` and `tuple_B = (5,6,1,2,3,4)`, then `tuple_A` is a subset of `tuple_B`. Are you OK with that? Also what if the values of `tuple_A` are randomly spread within `tuple_B`. Will you still consider `tuple_A` a subset of `tuple_B` ?  Can you clarify all this in your question please

Comment: Please clarify your question! Be more precise about your definition of "subset", adding more examples would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

This is short, but not the most efficient:

```
def tupleMatch(A,B): return A == tuple(b for b in B if b in A)

print(tupleMatch((1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4,5,6))) # True
print(tupleMatch((1,2,3,4),(1,3,5,4,2,6))) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify my solution based on the comment of @Mark Ransom - Thanks @Mark Ransom

Try

```
 if (', ' + str(A)[1:-1] + ', ') in (', '+str(B)[1:-1]+', '):
   return True
else:
   return False
```

***Verification***

Verification 1:

```
A=(1,2,3)
B=(1,2,3,4)
if (', ' + str(A)[1:-1] + ', ') in (', '+str(B)[1:-1]+', '):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('No')
# results is 'yes'
```

Verification 2:

```
A=(1,2,3)
B=(101,2,3,4)
if (', ' + str(A)[1:-1] + ', ') in (', '+str(B)[1:-1]+', '):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('No')
# results is 'No'
```

***Old caceled solution:***

```
if str(A)[1:-1] in str(B)[1:-1]:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

Comment: Clever, but gives wrong answer if `A=(1,2,3)` and `B=(101,2,3)`.

Comment: I modify my solution based on the comment of @Mark Ransom

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(tuple_A,tuple_B):
    for a,b in zip(tuple_A,tuple_B):
        if a!=b: 
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: It's not clear in the question if the match has to be at the *beginning* of the tuples.

Comment: The match has to be at the beginning of the tuple

Comment: The subset can be at position 0 in tuple_B or later. How are you managing that?

Comment: Indeed OP seems to be confused about the actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative method is;

```
tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)
tuple_B = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
A_str_rep = ''.join(str(digit) for digit in tuple_A)
B_str_rep = ''.join(str(digit) for digit in tuple_B)
print(B_str_rep.startswith(A_str_rep))
```

But, this won't be an ideal method for tuples containing large number of data. According to your requirement as the tuple B should start with tuple A, this method works.

Answer (score 0):

I think python's Algorithm is smarter than that. I tried your code and it gives me the requested answer.

**Code Syntax**

```
print(set(tuple_A).issubset(tuple_B))
```

**Output**

```
True

[Program finished]
```

I will assume that it gives you `False`, I will recommend you to use `sorted()`. In case that tuple is immutable object. We're going to play with the tuple as a list then convert it at the same time without playing in its memory address.

**Code Syntax**

```
tuple_A = (1,2,3,4)
tuple_B = (1,3,5,4,2,6)

print(set(tuple_A).issubset(tuple(sorted(tuple_B))))

# Check why the above print gives `True`
print("*"*40)

print(f"Tuple B before sorting: {tuple_B}\nTuple B after sorting: {tuple(sorted(tuple_B))}")
```

**Output**

```
True
****************************************
Tuple B before sorting: (1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6)
Tuple B after sorting: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

[Program finished]
```